# how to get average of values based on matcching object keys [code]

Tags: javascript

I have a array of object and I need to get the result based on few condition.
if Object.Keys() matches and type is integer, return average of those values.
if Object.keys() matches and type is string, return value with how many times it has appeared.

I have added the expectedResult at the bottom, have tried some methods but finding it hard to get the desired result.

looking forward to some helpful answers. thx

```js
let data = [{
        baySize: {type: "integer", value: "180"},
        bayAge: {type: "integer", value: "20"},
        totalBays: {type: "integer", value: "30"},
        bayType: {type: "string", value: "Brown"},
        sprayed: {type: "boolean", value: "No"}
        },
        {
        baySize: {type: "integer", value: "120"},
        bayAge: {type: "integer", value: "30"},
        totalBays: {type: "integer", value: "30"},
        bayType: {type: "string", value: "Grey"},
        sprayed: {type: "boolean", value: "No"}
}]

const result = data.map((item) => {
  const intType = Object.keys(item).map((values) => {
    return item[values].type == "integer" ? item[values].value : 0
  })
  const stringType = Object.keys(item).map((values) => {
    return item[values].type == "string" ? item[values].value : 0
  })
  console.log(intType)
  console.log(stringType)
})


let expectedResult = [{
  baySize: {type: "integer", value: "300"},
  bayAge: {type: "integer", value: "50"},
  totalBays: {type: "integer", value: "60"},
  bayType: {type: "string", value: "brown (1), Grey(1)"}
}]
```

Comment: You mean sum of them, not average, right?

Comment: @norbitrial, yes average of values for integer. I guess generally we do sum of values and then get the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = [{
        baySize: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "180"
        },
        bayAge: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "20"
        },
        totalBays: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "30"
        },
        bayType: {
            type: "string",
            value: "Brown"
        },
        sprayed: {
            type: "boolean",
            value: "No"
        }
    },
    {
        baySize: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "120"
        },
        bayAge: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "30"
        },
        totalBays: {
            type: "integer",
            value: "30"
        },
        bayType: {
            type: "string",
            value: "Grey"
        },
        sprayed: {
            type: "boolean",
            value: "No"
        }
    }
]
const intResult = {}
const strResult = {}
data.forEach(item => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        const innerItem = item[key]
        if (innerItem.type === 'integer') {
            if (!intResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                intResult[key] = {
                    count: 1,
                    value: +innerItem.value
                }
            } else {
                intResult[key].count++
                intResult[key].value += (+innerItem.value)
            }
        } else {
            if (!strResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                strResult[key] = {}
            }
            if (!strResult[key].hasOwnProperty(innerItem.value)) {
                strResult[key][innerItem.value] = 1
            } else {
                strResult[key][innerItem.value]++
            }

        }
    })
})
const resultObj = {}
Object.keys(intResult).forEach(key => {
    resultObj[key] = {
        type: 'integer',
        value: intResult[key].value / intResult[key].count + ''
    }
})

Object.keys(strResult).forEach(key => {
    let value = ''
    Object.keys(strResult[key]).forEach(subKey => {
        value += `${subKey}(${strResult[key][subKey]})`
    })
    resultObj[key] = {
        type: 'string',
        value
    }
})
console.log(resultObj)
```

Comment: Expect a better idea ^_^